# How to Build Level and bring Actors to Editor with C++ instead of Drag&Drop in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

How can you build level through C++ in unreal engine?
What I mean is that usually you drag and drop actors from "Place Actors", however, lets say I wish to make
a grid of actors / tiles, 50x50. Surely I wont drag and drop 2500 tiles(boxes) to Editor.
How can I do this with C++?

Note that I dont mean Actor spawing which is done at runtime, I wish to build level in editor.
I looked at Unreal Documents and every method there is shown as Drag & Drop.

Comment: Youe best bet is actually probably to use blueprint, epic has some [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Editor/ScriptingAndAutomation/Blueprints/index.html). You can still implement your logic in C++ by writing a blueprintcallable library function and wrap that up in an editor utility widget. The alternative is extending the editor itself, the easiest way to get started with that is to create a slate plugin (but I think it's really overkill for this). You can also write editor utilities with python on more recent versions of unreal.

Comment: Also as a side note, you really don't want 2,500 separate mesh actors unnecessarily. I'd suggest merging them into one as part of your utility.

Comment: Thank You! Jea not planning to do 2500 actors just example. Ill look into blueprints, not really used them so far.

Comment: Of course you could do this in c++ with an editor plugin. Find a built-in tool that does something similar to what you want and look at its source code.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: No, I was working on it during summer but then school started so Ive been busy with other things.